# How to get previous element which has a specific element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to select the element for previous element which holds a specific element.
Hard to understand let me explain in that way.

HTML (DOM):

```
<div><a></a></div>

<div><p class="selectThis"></p></div> ------
                                           -
<div><a></a></div>                         - select from previous element which holds class
                                           -
<div><p class="fromThis"></p></div> --------
```

What I tried before:

```
 $('.fromThis').parent().prev(); //
```

Comment: Do they both share a single ancestor somewhere? Then you could use closest() to traverse up to said ancestor, and use find() to target the selectThis element.

Comment: yeah but have to find the previous one

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the prettiest, but it selects the element and adds a class

jQuery solution

```js
$("a").on("click", function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().prevAll().find(".selectThis").css({"background": "gold"});
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><a></a></div>

<div><p class="selectThis">This is a paragraph</p></div> 
<div><a href="www.google.com">Select previous class</a></div>                        
<div><p class="fromThis"></p></div>
```

When you click on a link, the default behavior is to open a new tab. To prevent this, we can call the `preventDefault` action.

To find the div with a class of `selectThis`, we traverse upward to find the parent element, traverse backwards to find its sibling element. To find the sibling's children, we use the `find()` method.

Comment: I think you mean prevAll() instead of prev()

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
 $('.fromThis').parent().prevAll().find('.selectThis');
```

From the level of the divs you will select all previous siblings (i.e. the other divs) on this level. Then all descendants of the divs with the `selectThis` class are selected. So it does not only necessarily select on element or the closest to `fromThis` but a whole set of elements if there are more.

If it is important that you only select the element closest to your original element, you have to extend the expression like this:

```
 $('.fromThis').parent().prevAll().find('.selectThis').last();
```

Answer (score 0):

My solutions is to: find the first parent, then all the siblings and so filtering for class:

```
$('.fromThis').parent().siblings().find('.selectThis')
```